# Error when installing cordova sqlite plugin in ionic 3 app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to install cordova-sqlite-plugin using this commande:

> cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage --save

But I'm getting this error:

> (node:3088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Current working directory is not a
>   Cordova-based project.
>   (node:3088) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
>   will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

My cordova version is 8.0.0
My ionic version is 3.19.1

Comment: I've Just fixed it.

Comment: You can answer your own question with steps on how you managed to fix your problem so that other people with the same problem in the future can come across your post and view the solution